# How to print fields using multiple field separators

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I'm looking to print the 2nd and last column values using spaces and dots to separate the data.

My input is

```
abcds 874598 thd/vb.sbds/jf 48459 com.dat.first.NAME
```

Required output is

```
874598 NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[. ]' '{print $2, $NF}' file
874598 NAME
```

The `-F` option sets the fields separate which we provide a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) containing a space or a period. Awk spilt each line in the file into fields using the field separator values and stores them in incrementing references, `$1` being the first field, `$2` the second ect. `NF` is the reference to the number of fields in the current record and `$NF` is value of the last field.

You can read the command as:

```
awk               # the command; awk takes a script and executes it on every input line
-F'[. ]'          # the field separator; break each line up using spaces or periods
'{print $2, $NF}' # the script to execute; print the second and last field on every line
 file             # the input file to run the script on
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `read` and pure BASH:

```
s='abcds 874598 thd/vb.sbds/jf 48459 com.dat.first.NAME'
IFS=$' \t.' read -ra arr <<< "$s"
echo "${arr[1]} ${arr[-1]}"
874598 NAME
```

**Breakdown:**

```
IFS=' .'    # sets input field separator as space or dot
read -ra    # reads all fields into an array
${arr[1]}   # represents 2nd element in array
${arr[-1]}  # represents last element in array
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried first one(awk), the output is fine but for long list like below its not giving proper results,                                                                                      abcdef   28295     1  2 01:48 ?        00:01:26 /apps/local/share/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java -classpath ./thfd-1.0-SNAPSHOT-with-dependencies.jar:/drags/theme/nod/ojdf/config -javaagent:./spring-instrument-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/drags/theme/thisone/tdfh_thdi.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.key=/drags/theme/thisone/PML_thdi.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.key=Client com.twishe.dgfcc.ilem.MainCLass

Comment: With your long line I get `28295 MainCLass` as output. What else did you expect?

Comment: Thanks, Again, I got it, actually in my requirement, in place of space it is seperated by TAB, so how can we get it that

Comment: You just need to change `IFS` for handling tabs. See updated answer.

Comment: Its been great, if you pelase help me in using the awk command, As I am new to Unix, and awk, I tried on my input but not getting the output

Comment: Equivalent awk command will be this: `awk -F '[[:blank:].]' '{print $2, $NF}' <<< "$s"`

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it sounds like you want:

```
$ awk -F '[[:space:]]+|[.]' '{print $2, $NF}' file
874598 NAME
```

or:

```
$ awk '{sub(/.*\./,"",$NF); print $2, $NF}' file  
874598 NAME
```